# How to translate photo manipulation ("photoshopping") and the resulting manipulated image?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you translate the process of manipulating images, often called "photoshopping" in English, and how do you call the resulting manipulated image? I mean changing images from [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Voroshilov,_Molotov,_Stalin,_with_Nikolai_Yezhov.jpg) to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:The_Commissar_Vanishes_2.jpg).

I started out thinking about *bildmanipuli*/*bildmanipulo*, but from vortaro.net those don't seem to have the right meaning.

Some variation of the word *retuŝi* seems promising, but it only appears once in the tekstaro.

Answer (score 5):

PIV restricts *manipuli* to mean either "wield or operate with the bare hands" or "guide or alter clandestinely" but my impression is that it is nowadays used in pretty much exactly the same way as the English word *manipulate*.

The translators for the GNU Image Manipulation Program chose to call it a ***bildmanipulilo***. You can browse the translation [here](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/gimp/+pots/gimp20/eo/+translate). More generally, however, I think any program to edit files is called a *redaktilo*, so an image editor is a ***bildoredaktilo***. A retouched photo is a *retuŝita foto*. A modified image is a *modifita bildo*.

- *redakti* — to edit
- *ŝanĝi* — to alter
- *modifi* — to modify
- *retuŝi* — to retouch
- *bildoredaktado* — image editing
- *bildoredaktilo* — image editor
- *fotoredaktado* — photo editing
- *fotoredaktilo* — photo editor
- *rastrumera redaktilo* — raster editor
- *vektora redaktilo* — vector editor
- *bildodosiero* — image file

You can find more Esperanto computing terms at [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/index_eo.php).